# Efficient union of features by attributes using simple features (SF) in r?

Tags: r, r-sf

I would like to merge/combine/union different features within a shapefile by attribute value. A simple, motivating example would be to recreate state shapefiles from a geographic dataset that included counties with state ids.

I developed a simple loop code (see min reproducible example below) to do this by each level of attribute value, but this is slow. Further, it has been ingrained in me to avoid loops like this when possible. There doesn't seem to be a faster way to do this in simple features in R...

```r
library(sf)
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

i <- 1
for (ch in levels(as.factor(nc$SID74))) {
  nc_temp <- nc %>% filter(SID74==ch) %>%
    st_union() %>% 
    st_sf()
  nc_temp$SID74 <- ch
  if (i==1) {
    nc_union = nc_temp
  } else {
    nc_union <- rbind(nc_union, nc_temp)
  }
  i <- i+1
}
```

The above code performs the required task, but is relatively slow. [I know I could speed it up by pre-allocating memory.] Is their a more efficient, single command way of performing this task?

Comment: `nc_union <- nc %>%
  group_by(SID74) %>%
  summarise(geometry = st_union(geometry))` ?

Comment: Simplifying what @Chris says, just `summarise` without a function should calculate the union by default

Comment: An answer for you might actually be in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44314922/5325862)'s question

Comment: Works like a charm -- I didn't realize (but should have suspected) that `dplyr::summarize` works on `sf` objects. Thanks @Chris and @camille

Comment: Hi guys, this won't do the job. It will return a `data.frame` object and loss all the `geometry` information.